# pytest: Executing multiple tests at once

Tags: pytest

I want to execute multiple tests at once but am getting a nastygram:

```
pytest tests -k '1.1.18 or 4.1.12 or 6.1.11 or 6.1.12' ...

...

ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': 1.1.18 or 4.1.12 or 6.1.11 or 6.1.12
```

`pytest tests -k 1.1.18 ...` works fine to execute one test.  My team has structured our tests using suite files that are specific to OS distros and associate the test numbers with scripts & methods like so:

```
tests:
- test_function: "foo.py:test_bar1"
  test_id: "1.1.1.1"
- test_function: "foo.py:test_bar2"
  test_id: "1.2"
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what is your test layout? Are these numbers nested modules?

Comment: They're not really nested modules.  I don't know all the ins and outs of how my teams tests are set up.  I will update the original post with more details.

Comment: Thanks - can you please specify what you mean by test id? Are these parametrized tests, and these are parameter ids? Or are they custom markers, or something else I just don't know?

Comment: "Are these parametrized tests, and these are parameter ids? Or are they custom markers?"  I'm not sure what to call them.  I'll try to read up these things in pytest to try to figure it out.

Comment: You could just show an example test to clarify this (e.g. to see where the id is defined).

Answer (score 0):

First `pip install pytest-xdist`
Then use `pytest -n NUM` where NUM is the integer of the number you want running in parrallel.

So to run 3 in parallel.

`pytest -n3`

Or

`pytest -n 3`

Documentation link:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/xdist.html

EDIT

---

`-k` takes test function names. You want them to be unique.

```
tests:
- test_function1: "foo.py:test_bar1"
  test_id: "1.1.1.1"
- test_function2: "foo.py:test_bar2"
  test_id: "1.2"
...
```

---

```
pytest -k "test_function1 or test_function1"
```

Note in windows cmd you must use `"` not `'`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I don't want to run in parallel.  I want to run N tests serially.